# Getting HTML of Smart Form Content in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I am working in Ektron 8.0.

I have created a smart form configuration in Settings,I assigned this particular smart form configuration for
a Folder and created a Smart form content.Now i am trying to access the Smart Form content programmatically.
I am getting the "XML" data as the content.Html property.Is there is any way i can get the HTML data corresponding to a smartform content,rather than these XML data?

Comment: The HTML content of the user entered data or the HTML markup of the SmarForm UI that the content editor uses?

Comment: The smart form content's HTML,which includes the configuration UI+the user entered Input

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your use case where you need to do this?

Comment: @Charles Wesley : I need to send smart form content to a third party

Comment: @Bisileesh, that link is broken above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to this, here are two.

**XSLT:**

```
 <CMS:ContentBlock runat="server" Visible="true" DisplayXslt="/xmlfiles/SmartForm.xslt" DefaultContentID="23" />
```

The SmartForm.xslt file translates the xml into formatted html.

**Use XSD to access SmartForm Content on the code behind.**

This article explains the process.
http://developer.ektron.com/Templates/KBDetail.aspx?id=603

You need to get a copy of the .xsd file and use it to create an object definition for your smart form.

Use the xsd.exe tool to create a class. The command looks like this.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\xsd.exe" "C:\inetpub\site\xsd\SmartFormContet.xsd" /classes /language:CS /namespace:SmartForm.SmartFormContent
```

This will generate a class file named SmartFormContet.cs

Copy this file and paste into the code behind of the page.

Deserialize the XML from the Content.Html property.

Comment: Thanks for the response,i am looking for a generalized approach that will work for any smartform content without generating class for each smartform content.

Comment: I would use xslt. It is really simple once you get your head around it. If you post a copy of the smartform xml and the desired xsl, I can give you a brief example.